# BDD - Test something is on every page

Tags: bdd, behat

We have a feature in our BDD test suite that describes that a specific link should appear at the top of every page, in our admin system.

How should we test this? Right now we have a scenario outline run through with 4 examples, 1 is the admin dashboard, and the other three are various actions you can do in the admin like edit something or view a list.

Ideas?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer may be unpopular! :)

Personally, I doubt I would test the existence of the link at all with an automated test...it's going to be slow especially if you do decide to test it on each page.  If you test the functionality behind the link in another test you can be confident that the link works (otherwise how did you get to it in the other test?).

Use a degree of pragmatism, if it really is crucial to check the link then check the code that generates it and if it is reused on each page then write one test and be brave and assume it'll be on the rest.

Answer (score 0):

What would happen if you deleted the line of code that shows the link? I'd hope that the link would no longer appear on any of the admin pages. If thats the case a pragmatic approach would be to write a single test that shows the link appears on one admin page. This will break if someone mucks up the code that shows the link.

This is using a test to provide protection against a regression, its not BDD. However its a practical approach to deal with a bug.

Comment: How do you protect against regression then?